# Exception handling aware of execution flow

Tags: c++, exception

### Edit:

For personn interested in a cleaner way to implemenent that, have a look to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847279/code-reuse-in-exception-handling/847316#847316).

---

In my job I often need to use third-made API to access remote system.
For instance to create a request and send it to the remote system:

```
   #include "external_lib.h"
   void SendRequest(UserRequest user_request)
   {
       try
       {
           external_lib::Request my_request;
           my_request.SetPrice(user_request.price);
           my_request.SetVolume(user_request.quantity);
           my_request.SetVisibleVolume(user_request.quantity);
           my_request.SetReference(user_request.instrument);
           my_request.SetUserID(user_request.user_name);
           my_request.SetUserPassword(user_request.user_name);
           // Meny other member affectations ...
       }
       catch(external_lib::out_of_range_error& e)
       {
           // Price , volume ????
       }
       catch(external_lib::error_t& e)
       {
           // Here I need to tell the user what was going wrong
       }
   }
```

Each lib's setter do checks the values that the end user has provided, and may thow an exception when the user does not comply with remote system needs. For instance a specific user may be disallowed to send a too big volume. That's an example, and actually many times users tries does not comply: no long valid instrument, the prices is out of the limit, etc, etc.
*Conseqently, our end user **need** an explicit error message to tell him what to modify in its request to get a second chance to compose a valid request. I have to provide hiim such hints*

Whatever , external lib's exceptions (mostly) never specifies which field is the source
of aborting the request.

What is the best way, according to you, to handle those exceptions?

My first try at handling those exceptions was to "wrap" the Request class with mine. Each setters are then wrapped in a method which does only one thing : a try/catch block. The catch block then throws a new exceptions of mine : my_out_of_range_volume, or my_out_of_range_price depending on the setter. For instance SetVolume() will be wrapped this way:

```
My_Request::SetVolume(const int volume) 
{
    try
    {
        m_Request.SetVolume(volume);
    }
    catch(external_lib::out_range_error& e)
    {
        throw my_out_of_range_volume(volume, e);
    }
}
```

What do you think of it? What do you think about the exception handling overhead it implies? ... :/

Well the question is open, I need new idea to get rid of that lib constraints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there really are a lot of methods you need to call, you could cut down on the code using a [reflection library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/libreflection.aspx), by creating just one method to do the calling and exception handling, and passing in the name of the method/property to call/set as an argument. You'd still have the same amount of try/catch calls, but the code would be simpler and you'd already know the name of the method that failed.

Alternatively, depending on the type of exception object that they throw back, it may contain stack information or you could use another library to walk the stack trace to get the name of the last method that it failed on. This depends on the platform you're using.

Comment: refletion library is a good point, and is close to Neil's proposition(?). About the stack information: it is really a good point. While I can't modify the lib I use, do you know how to get this information when catching exceptions it throws back to me?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer a wrapper whenever I'm using third party library. 
It allows me to define my own exception handling mechanism avoiding users of my class to know about external library.
Also, if later the third party changes the exception handling to return codes then my users need not be affected.

But rather than throwing the exception back to my users I would implement the error codes. Something like this:

```
class MyRequest
{
    enum RequestErrorCode
    {
        PRICE_OUT_OF_LIMIT,
        VOLUME_OUT_OF_LIMIT,
        ...
        ...
        ...
    };

    bool SetPrice(const int price , RequestErrorCode& ErrorCode_out);

    ...

private:

    external_lib::Request mRequest;


};

bool MyRequest::SetPrice(const int price , RequestErrorCode& ErrorCode_out)
{
    bool bReturn = true;
    try
    {

        bReturn = mRequest.SetPrice(price);
    }
    catch(external_lib::out_of_range_error& e)
    {

        ErrorCode_out = PRICE_OUT_OF_LIMIT;
        bReturn = false;
    }
    return bReturn;
}



      bool SendRequest(UserRequest user_request)
{
    MyRequest my_request;
    MyRequest::RequestErrorCode anErrorCode;
    bool bReturn = my_request.SetPrice(user_request.price, anErrorCode);
    if( false == bReturn)
    {
        //Get the error code and process
        //ex:PRICE_OUT_OF_LIMIT
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering to do that instead of a double/nested  try/catch block as my soltution do. But return check will be done eveytime and cost a little bit. why not relying on exception the external lib forces me to  use it. And it get the code cleaner , don't you think ?

Comment: Actually, instead of a code, make it a string or a class. When there's an error, the MySetFunc method appends the error to the string. Then you only have to check if the string contains something at the end. With a code, it'll be overwritten on each call and you need ifs after every call.

Comment: @yves Baumes, My intension was to avoid throwing another exception.Also, the return code need to be checked only in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

In your first version, you could report the number of operations that succeeded provided the `SetXXX` functions return some value. You could also keep a counter (which increases after every `SetXXX` call in that `try` block) to note what all calls succeeded and based on that counter value, return an appropriate error message.

The major problem with validating each and every step is, in a real-time system -- you are probably introducing too much latency.

Otherwise, your second option looks like the only way. Now, if you have to write a wrapper for every library function and why not add the validation logic, if you can, instead of making the actual call to the said library? This IMO, is more efficient.

Comment: About the "counter" solution, you're right but what i don't like is the fact to maintain a counter that could be not used in as of sucess of this request. But nevertheless the overhead is not big compared to all the stuff around. thank you!

Comment: About the Logic validation (a kind of pre-check). Acutally condition evolves in real time (price range for instance) and I need to rely on this library (communicating with the remote system AFAIK) not to have false negative (a request rejected while it could be ok)

Comment: I can see where you are coming from. I meant *only those* validations that can be reliably done on the users' end should be done there, for others you have to talk to your server, e.g: the user may have a small account and cannot place an order worth x$. This is an invariant.

Comment: Another thing with validation is you will need online/offline synchronization (and periodic updation of user data).

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case I might dare a macro. Something like (not tested, backslashes omitted):

```
#define SET( ins, setfun, value, msg )                           
  try {
    ins.setfun( value );
  }
  catch( external::error & )  {
    throw my_explanation( msg, value );
  }
```

and in use:

```
Instrument i;
SET( i, SetExpiry, "01-01-2010", "Invalid expiry date" );
SET( i, SetPeriod, 6, "Period out of range" );
```

You get the idea.

Comment: that's a good point , that's actually what i've implemented ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not really the answer you are looking for, but i think that your external lib, or you usage of it, somehow abuses exceptions. An exception should not be used to alter the general process flow. If it is the general case, that the input does not match the specification, than it is up to your app to valid the parameter before passing it to the external lib. Exceptions should only be thrown if an "exceptional" case occurrs, and i think whenever it comes to doing something with user input, you usually have to deal with everything and not rely on 'the user has to provide the correct data, otherwise we handle it with exceptions'.

nevertheless, an alternative to Neil's suggestions could be using boost::lambda, if you want to avoid macros.

Comment: Yes you're right, usually in system we wrote, we avoid exceptions. But here the lib is made the way it is... So i need to enable exception is my program , and handle them eventually. Thnak you for the boost::lambda trick I will have a deeper look !